# Flatten XML to DataGridView using C#/Linq

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

There is many questions like this out there, but this one is quite unique I can assure you! I need a generic solution to flatten XML data to a two column grid (Field, Value) but the real challenge is the hierarchy of the XML data is different for each response!

This is audit data stored in a database in XML format, I cannot change the structure of these responses but need to handle any hierarchy possible and display the results to the user in a simple grid.

Here is a sample of the XML structure:

```
<xml>
  <results>
    <resultsDTO>
      <reportid>173601</reportid>
      <results>
        <displayName>Item 1</displayName>
        <someParameter>blahblah</someParameter>
        <hidden>false</hidden>
        <values>
          <value>10</value>
          <resultType>PERCENTAGE</resultType>
        </values>
        <values>
          <value>some.pdf</value>
          <resultType>PDF</resultType>
        </values>
        <values>
          <value>Findings of Item 1</value>
          <resultType>FINDINGS</resultType>
        </values>
      </results>
      <results>
        <displayName>Item 2</displayName>
        <someParameter>blahblah</someParameter>
        <hidden>false</hidden>
        <values>
          <value>20</value>
          <resultType>PERCENTAGE</resultType>
        </values>
        <values>
          <value/>
          <resultType>PDF</resultType>
        </values>
        <values>
          <value>Findings of Item 2</value>
          <resultType>FINDINGS</resultType>
        </values>
      </results>
      <reportTexts>
        <value/>
        <resultType>HISTORY</resultType>
      </reportTexts>
      <reportTexts>
        <value>Some info here.</value>
        <resultType>INFORMATION</resultType>
      </reportTexts>
    </resultsDTO>
  </results>
</xml>
```

As you can see from the XML there is always a "resultType" and "value" at the same level, however I need a way to iterate through this XML without defining any hardcoded paths (XML/Results/ResultsDTO/Results/Values/) that will find these resultTypes and values at any level and also handle a few special rules with the data.

I'm trying to get these values into a GridView output like this:

```
[Field], [Value]
Item 1 - Percentage, 10
Item 1 - Findings, Findings of Item 1
Item 2 - Percentage, 20
Item 2 - Findings, Findings of Item 2
History, NULL
Information, Some info here.
```

Here is my current code which is displaying half of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
var query = from c in doc.Descendants("xml").Elements("results").Elements("resultsDTO").Elements("results").Elements("values").Where(n => n.Element("resultType").Value != "PDF")
            select new
            {
                Field = c.Parent.Element("displayName") == null ? c.Element("resultType").Value : c.Parent.Element("displayName").Value + " - " + c.Element("resultType").Value,
                Value = c.Element("value").Value        
            };
dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

I'm suppressing the "PDF" resultType from showing and also appending the displayName to the resultType if it exists in the parent! as it does not for other nodes.

This is currently only getting the values under XML/Results/ResultsDTO/Results/Values/ and not the values within XML/Results/ResultsDTO/ReportTexts.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right for the most part. All you need to do is:

1. Union the Descendants of **reportTexts** elements as well.
2. Descendants don't need you to traverse a path. you can give any starting path.

Use the following query:

```
 var query = from c in doc.Descendants("values").Union(doc.Descendants("reportTexts")).Where(n => n.Element("resultType").Value != "PDF")
             select new
             {
              Field = c.Parent.Element("displayName") == null ? c.Element("resultType").Value : c.Parent.Element("displayName").Value + " - " + c.Element("resultType").Value,
              Value = c.Element("value").Value // you can replace "" by null here
             };
```

Output is as follows:

```
[Field], [Value]
Item 1 - Percentage, 10
Item 1 - Findings, Findings of Item 1
Item 2 - Percentage, 20
Item 2 - Findings, Findings of Item 2
History, ""
Information, Some info here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the Descendants explanation, this worked wonderfully!